# Create newshadetheorem without numbering

Tags: numbering

I'm using the `shadethm.sty`-package and I want to suppress numbering for a certain theorem, but command `\newshadetheorem*` is undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `ntheorem` package allows to define different kinds of unnumbered theorems, and shaded theorems thaat can break across pages, which `shadethm` cannot do, as far as I know.

Comment: Welcome :) you might like to have a look at the mdframed or tcolorbox packages

Comment: I'm the author of shadethm.  I suggest that you go with a more modern package, such as has been suggested by others.  At one time it was the only way to do a certain job but now there are better ways.

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution with the `tcolorbox` package and the `theorems` library belonging to it. To give an unnumbered theorem, just specify `theorem name` as an option.

The precise form, the colors, filling, shades, shadows can be specified later on, but as there are no further conditions given, I restricted to the easiest form.

\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

```
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage[theorems,breakable]{tcolorbox}%


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
 \section{First}

\newtcbtheorem{lem}{Lemma}{%
        theorem name,%
        colback=green!5,%
        colframe=green!35!black,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,title after break={Lemma  -- \raggedleft Continued}%
    }{lem}


\begin{lem}{On Brontosaurs}{}
\textbf{By Ann Elk (Misses)}

Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again on the other end. 
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try with the [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) package. it can create beautiful shaded *regions* as you can see in its [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mdframed/mdframed.pdf), with its *command* `\newmdenv[<options>]{env-name}`.

This package has the advantage that the contents of the environment can break across the pages if it's necessary.

It is also possible to define your own *style* for the options with the command `\mdfdefinestyle{<style name>}{<options>}`. For this particular case i defined the style `myshadedthm` for the theorems (and others structures what i want use) and i call it with `style=<style name>`.

```
\mdfdefinestyle{myshadedthm}{backgroundcolor=gray!20,linewidth=0pt,innerleftmargin=1ex}
```

As it's explained in the code if you use the `amsthm` package, this adds a extra space on top of theorem, and this can fix append to the style the option `innertopmargin=-0.5ex`. (If you use `ntheorem` this fix must not do).

### Defining theorems in `mdframed`

`mdframed` relies in the *command* `\newmdtheoremenv` with the same syntax of `\newtheorem` except that it has an first *optional* argument for `[<options>]` of `mdframed`.

Compare

```
\newmdtheoremenv[<mdframed-options>]{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
\newtheorem{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
```

Unfortunately there is not a starred version of `\newmdtheoremenv` with the same use than `\newtheorem*{<envname>}{<caption>}` but we can redefine the command `\newmdtheoremenv` for *achieving* this goal:

#### Redefinition of `\newmdtheoremenv` for accepting a starred version

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\newmdtheoremenv{s O{} m o m o }{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
   \newtheorem*{#3}{#5}%
 }{%
 \ifboolexpr{ test {\IfNoValueTF {#4}} and test {\IfNoValueTF {#6}} }%
    {\newtheorem{#3}{#5}}{%
     \IfValueTF{#4}{\newtheorem{#3}[#4]{#5}}{}%
     \IfValueTF{#6}{\newtheorem{#3}{#5}[#6]}{}%
    }
  }%
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{#3}{%
     \begin{mdframed}[#2]}%
  \AfterEndEnvironment{#3}{%
     \end{mdframed}}%
}
```

Here's an example of what we can do with this:

### The Full Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For using `gray!20` for example
%--------------------------------
% Redefinition of `\newmdtheoremenv` for accepting a starred version
\DeclareDocumentCommand\newmdtheoremenv{s O{} m o m o }{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
   \newtheorem*{#3}{#5}%
 }{%
 \ifboolexpr{ test {\IfNoValueTF {#4}} and test {\IfNoValueTF {#6}} }%
    {\newtheorem{#3}{#5}}{%
     \IfValueTF{#4}{\newtheorem{#3}[#4]{#5}}{}%
     \IfValueTF{#6}{\newtheorem{#3}{#5}[#6]}{}%
    }
  }%
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{#3}{%
     \begin{mdframed}[#2]}%
  \AfterEndEnvironment{#3}{%
     \end{mdframed}}%
}
%--------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\mdfdefinestyle{myshadedthm}{backgroundcolor=gray!20,linewidth=0pt,innerleftmargin=1ex,%
%--------------------------------
% If you use `amsthm` can adjust `innertopmargin` to avoid extra space in top.
innertopmargin=-0.5ex% % Comment or remove this line if you use `ntheorem`.
%--------------------------------
}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myshadedthm]{stheorem}[theorem]{Theorem}
\newmdtheoremenv*[style=myshadedthm]{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
Text
\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ \dots (a normal theorem)
\end{theorem}
Text
\begin{stheorem}
If $a$, $b$ and $c$ \dots (a shaded theorem)
\end{stheorem}
More text
\begin{lemma}
Like $a^2=a$ we have \dots (shaded) and no numbered
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo of what can be done with the `ntheorem` and `framed` packages. Framed or shaded theorems can break across pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, x11names]{book}%]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{pstricks} %
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed} %
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}%

    \theoreminframepostskip{1ex}
    \shadecolor{Thistle3!30!}
    \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\color{Tomato4}\sffamily\bfseries}
    \theoremseparator{.}
    \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
    \newshadedtheorem{thm}{Theorem}%\danger

\begin{document}

\vspace*{0.6\textheight}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{thm}[unnumbered]
\lipsum[1]\vskip-3\baselineskip
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]